# NativeProcess communication giving error

Tags: python, actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to communicate to a python script through actionscript. it gives me error on line : 
 
`var stdOut:ByteArray = process.standardOutput;`
from the function shown below :

```
public function onOutputData(event:ProgressEvent):void 
{ 
    var stdOut:ByteArray = process.standardOutput; //error
    var data:String = stdOut.readUTFBytes(process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable); 
    trace("Got: ", data); 
}
```

Error is:

> Implicit coercion of a value with static type IDataInput to a possibly
>   unrelated type ByteArray.

I am following the same approach as on Adobe's page. Here is some testable code :

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.desktop.NativeProcessStartupInfo;
    import flash.filesystem.File;
    import flash.desktop.NativeProcess;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public class InstaUtility extends Sprite
    {
        public var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new     NativeProcessStartupInfo();
        public var file:File = new File("C:/Python27/python.exe");
        public var process:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
        public function InstaUtility()
        {
            nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;
            nativeProcessStartupInfo.workingDirectory =     File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(".");
            trace("Location " + File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(".").nativePath);
            var processArgs:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
            processArgs[0] = "test.py";
            nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = processArgs;
            var process:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
            process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData); 
            process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo); 
        }   
        public function onOutputData(event:ProgressEvent):void 
        { 
            var stdOut:ByteArray = process.standardOutput; //error
            var data:String = stdOut.readUTFBytes(process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable); 
            trace("Got: ", data); 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Also getting runtime error : "Main Thread (Suspended: Error: Error #3219: The NativeProcess could not be started. 'Not supported in current profile.') "

Comment: `if(NativeProcess.isSupported)
            {
                go();
            }` Note that "The NativeProcess class and its capabilities are only available to AIR applications installed with a native installer (extended desktop profile applications)."

Answer (score 0):

> The NativeProcess could not be started. Not supported in current
>   profile.

Are you testing in Flash IDE?

- **Test within IDE** : In your AIR Publish Settings make sure you ticked only "**extended Desktop**" when debugging through IDE. This way you also get traces etc.
- **Test after Publish** : You must tick both "**Desktop**" and "**extended Desktop**" and also tick "**Windows Installer (.exe)**". Install your App using the generated **.exe** file (not the **.air** file).

> Implicit coercion of a value with static type IDataInput to a possibly
>   unrelated type ByteArray.

`var stdOut:ByteArray = process.standardOutput; //error` is not how it's done!! Don't make any **var** each time the progress event fires up. Each firing holds around **32kb** or **64kb** of bytes only (can't remember), so if the expected result is larger it will continue to fire in multiple chunks... Use and recycle a  single `public byteArray` to hold all the result data.

Try a setup like below :

```
//# Declare the public variables
public var stdOut : ByteArray = new ByteArray();
public var data_String : String = "";
```

Your process also needs a **NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT** listener.

```
process.addEventListener(NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT, on_Process_Exit );
```

Before you `.start` a process, also clear the byteArray ready for new data with `stdOut.clear();`.

Now your **progressEvent** can look like this below... *(Process puts result data into **stdOut** bytes)*.

```
public function onOutputData (event:ProgressEvent) : void 
{ 
    //var stdOut:ByteArray = process.standardOutput; //error

    //# Progress could fire many times so keep adding data to build the final result
    //# "stdOut.length" will be zero at first but add more data to tail end (ie: length)
    process.standardOutput.readBytes( stdOut, stdOut.length, process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable );

    //# Below should be in a Process "Exit" listener but might work here too
    stdOut.position = 0; //move pointer back before reading bytes
    data_String = stdOut.readUTFBytes( stdOut.length ); 
    trace("function onOutputData -- Got : "  + data_String ); 
}
```

But you really need to add an "**onProcessExit**" listener and then only check for results when the process itself has completed. *(Tracing here is much safer for a guaranteed result)*.

```
public function on_Process_Exit (event : NativeProcessExitEvent) : void 
{
    trace ("PYTHON Process finished : ############# " )
    stdOut.position = 0; //# move pointer back before reading bytes
    data_String = stdOut.readUTFBytes( stdOut.length ); 
    trace("PYTHON Process Got : "  + data_String );

}
```